# Excel Worksheet_SelectionChange to select cell value in column 1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the value of the cell in column 1 of the clicked cell using the Worksheet_SelectionChange event, but can't seem to get the code to return anything???

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)

    Debug.Print Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug.Print shows in the immediate window of VB editor, use msgbox instead. your code is not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox Target.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value

End Sub
```